# Deactivate Installed Packages

Tags: apex, deactivate, installedpackage

I was trying to bulk convert some Leads into Contacts using Apex, but it always responded as an error such as:

> System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 2;
>   first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, System.LimitException: dupcheck:Too
>   many SOQL queries: 101 (dupcheck) : []

`dubcheck` is the namespace of an installed package which consists in a series of triggers for each SObject that checks for duplicates in the system. Is there a way I can deactivate the whole dubcheck or certain portions of it without fully deleting it?

I deactivated triggers before by changing the status to inactive from the xml file using the force.com ide for eclipse, but I cannot access installed packages data from here.

Comment: If you are lucky the package will have e.g. a public custom settings to turn the trigger off or otherwise configure it so it does nothing.

Comment: Can you check to see which Duplicate Catcher App you've installed that has that namespace? There isn't one called "DupCatch". There's DupeChecker by Symphonic Source and numerous others. It sounds like you'll want to contact support for the app.

Comment: thanks @ crmprogdev and @Keith C for your answers I'll try to see if I can contact their support